# Is this a correct use of switch case

Tags: java, selenium

I have a switch case with repeating codes inside like four of them(for arrowkeys but there are more other scenario) that only difference are, ArrowDown, ArrowUp, ArrowLeft and ArrowRight. Below is the snippet of code:

```
    switch (peformAction) {
    case "ArrowDown":
        CommonFunctions.silentWait(1);
        actionToE.moveToElement(currentObject).perform();

        if (CommonFunctions.isElementDisplayed(currentObject)) {
            if (CommonFunctions.isElementEnabled(currentObject)) {
                if (!actionPar.isEmpty()) {
                    int intActionPar = Integer.parseInt(actionPar);
                    for (int i = 0; i < intActionPar; i++) {
                        currentObject.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
                    }
                } else {
                    currentObject.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
                }
                isActionSuccess = true;
            }
        }

        break;


    case "ArrowLeft":
        CommonFunctions.silentWait(1);
        actionToE.moveToElement(currentObject).perform();

        if (CommonFunctions.isElementDisplayed(currentObject)) {
            if (CommonFunctions.isElementEnabled(currentObject)) {
                if (!actionPar.isEmpty()) {
                    int intActionPar = Integer.parseInt(actionPar);
                    for (int i = 0; i < intActionPar; i++) {
                        currentObject.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT);
                    }
                } else {
                    currentObject.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT);
                }
                isActionSuccess = true;
            }
        }

        break;
```

Questions:
1.) how can improve this code(suggestion)?
2.) would it be advisable to put try catch on each case?

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could avoid the switch by using a Map<String, Key> instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're repeating too much code. You should follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), i.e. *Don't Repeat Yourself*.

Two ways to do that:

- Use the `switch` to assign differing values to a variable, then have common code after the `switch` block.

  ```
  Keys key;
  switch (performAction) {
      case "ArrowDown":
          key = Keys.ARROW_DOWN;
          break;
      case "ArrowLeft":
          key = Keys.ARROW_LEFT;
          break;
      ...
      default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown action: " + performAction);
  }

  CommonFunctions.silentWait(1);
  actionToE.moveToElement(currentObject).perform();

  if (CommonFunctions.isElementDisplayed(currentObject)) {
      if (CommonFunctions.isElementEnabled(currentObject)) {
          if (!actionPar.isEmpty()) {
              int intActionPar = Integer.parseInt(actionPar);
              for (int i = 0; i < intActionPar; i++) {
                  currentObject.sendKeys(key);
              }
          } else {
              currentObject.sendKeys(key);
          }
          isActionSuccess = true;
      }
  }
  ```
- Move the common code to a method.

  ```
  switch (performAction) {
      case "ArrowDown":
          isActionSuccess = performAction(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, currentObject);
          break;
      case "ArrowLeft":
          isActionSuccess = performAction(Keys.ARROW_LEFT, currentObject);
          break;
      ...
  }
  ```

  ```
  private boolean performAction(Keys key, Xxx currentObject) {
      CommonFunctions.silentWait(1);
      actionToE.moveToElement(currentObject).perform();

      if (CommonFunctions.isElementDisplayed(currentObject)) {
          if (CommonFunctions.isElementEnabled(currentObject)) {
              if (!actionPar.isEmpty()) {
                  int intActionPar = Integer.parseInt(actionPar);
                  for (int i = 0; i < intActionPar; i++) {
                      currentObject.sendKeys(keys);
                  }
              } else {
                  currentObject.sendKeys(keys);
              }
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Andres... I guess I can put the try-catch handling to the method. :-)